# PHP same name magic methods in multiple traits

Tags: php, traits

How to resolve conflicts of traits having the same magic methods?

All __get methods from the traits and the extended class should be available. Ideally, I would like Foo::__get to be prioritised over Bar::__get, and Bar::__get over Test::__get.

```
trait Foo {
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (str_ends_with($name, 'Foo')) {
            return 'Foo';
        }

        return parent::__get($name);
    }
}

trait Bar {
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (str_ends_with($name, 'Bar')) {
            return 'Bar';
        }

        return parent::__get($name);
    }
}

class Test {
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (str_ends_with($name, 'Test')) {
            return 'Test';
        }

        null;
    }
}

class FooBar extends Test {
    use Foo, Bar; //What to do here to resolve issues?
}

$instance = new FooBar();
$instance->propertyFoo; //"Foo"
$instance->propertyBar; //"Bar"
$instance->propertyTest; //"Test"
$instance->propertyDemo; //null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to resolve a conflict, you need to [read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict). But according to your description, what you need to resolve is not a conflict, but a very specific problem. And unfortunately, because you called the `__get` method of the parent class in `Foo::__get`, you can't simply call them in turn. Anyway, we need to check the return value of `Foo::__get` first:

```php
class FooBar extends Test {
    use Foo, Bar {
        Foo::__get as fooget;
        Bar::__get as barget;
    }
    
    public function __get($name) {
        $ret = $this->fooget($name);
        return $ret != 'Foo' ? $this->barget($name) : $ret;
    }
}
```

Perhaps you need to reconsider your needs.

Comment: I hoped I missed something reading the manual or maybe there is some trick that is not mentioned there. Thank you for the explanation.